# need to reduce numbers similar an array (c ++)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

there are sorted in descending order of an array, it is necessary that two identical elements disappear, and instead enter a single 1 more 
like this:
[12 8 8 6 4 3 3] => [12 9 6 5 ]

I tried to like this but goes completely nonsense:

```
vector<int> v(c, c + mn);

for ( i = 0; i < mn; i++)
{
    if (v[i] == v[i + 1])
    {
        v[i]++;
        v.erase(v.begin() + i + 1);
        i = 0;
    }
    for (auto&x : v)std::cout << x << ".";
}
```

P.S.:sorry for bad english

Comment: Can you confirm that it's not just removing the duplicates, but that repeating 8 8 are replaced by a single 9  (1 more than 8) ?  And that this is repretitive so 3 3 is replaced by a signgle 4, which causes a double 4 in the list that shall be replaced by a 5 ?

Comment: Just for clarification:  You want to transform [12 8 8 6 4 3 3] into [12 9 6 5 ] with intermediate step [12 9 6 4 4] where duplicate elements with value n will be replaced by a single element with value n+1.

Comment: I would suggest using two iterators (dest and source) , instead of `erase`.  Just fix up the length once at the end.

Comment: Would that destroy the sorting?

Comment: Any memory requirements or complexity requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you do not go out of bounds:

- do not go until the last element to compare it with the non existing next one
- take into consideration that the removal of an item shrinks the size of the vector.

So some minor corrections get it to work:

```
  vector<int> v{12,8,8,6,4,3,3};
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size()-1; i++)
  {
    if (v[i] == v[i + 1])
    {
        v[i]++;
        v.erase(v.begin() + i + 1);
        i = 0;
    }
  }
  for (auto&x : v)std::cout << x << ".";
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/DQMvgH)

To avoid the multiple passes, you could also start from the end:

```
  for (int i = v.size()-2; i >=0; i--)
  {
    if (v[i] == v[i + 1])
    {
        v[i]++;
        v.erase(v.begin() + i + 1);
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**

@knivil's comment pointed out that more than 2 identical elements (for example 3 consecutive 8 instead of 2) could lead to inconsistencies in the vector (the final result being no longer sorted).  Here a modified version if these multiple repetitions would be a valid case  here a modified version (assuming that for n repetitions, it's still 1 more and not n-1 more):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size()-1; i++)
  {
    if (v[i] == v[i + 1])
    {
        while (i+1<v.size() && v[i+1]==v[i])
            v.erase(v.begin() + i + 1);
        v[i]++;
        i = 0;
    }
  }
  for (auto&x : v)std::cout << x << ".";
```

With a new [online demo](http://ideone.com/mcb0Nm).

I leave you as an exercise to make the single pass reverse version ;-)

Comment: What about { 12, 11, 11 , 6, 5, 3, 3 } ?

Comment: @knivil That's an interesting point.  The question spoke of two identical elements and adding one.  What if there are n same elements:  shall I add 1 or shall I add n-1 ?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my test case which should fit the problem description by not introducing more than 2 similar numbers.

Comment: You have out of bound access in your second snippet. and `{3, 3, 3}` would produce `{3, 4}` and not `{4, 3}`.

Comment: @knivil as your remark is perfectly valid, I've made an edit to address this possibiliy.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes !  true !  In fact I hesitated while I was writing between comparing v[i] with v[i-1] or continue with i and i+1, but forgot to update the starting bound.  I'll edit.  For the second remark, see my comment above, and my edit:  the question didn't address more than 2 repetitions.

Comment: @Christophe A very big thank you, you helped me a lot = *
 p.s. : C ++ makes me feel blonde

Answer (score 0):

One route is to use a hash map to basically look at the frequency of each element.  Then use the frequency information to increment data.

```
std::vector<int> result;
std::unordered_map<int, int> hashMap;
bool update = false;
for(auto cur : v) {
   hashMap[cur]++;  // intialize hash map with data
}
do {
   update = false;
   for (auto cur : hashMap) {
     if (cur.second == 2) {      // Process duplicate case
       hashMap[cur.first + 1]++; // add the +1 element
       hashMap.erase(cur.first); // remove the original
       update = true;            // set flag to perform another pass
     }
   }
} while(update);
for (auto cur : hashMap)
   result.push_back(cur.first);
std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(), std::greater<int>());
v = result;
```

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/gKzNqM).

Comment: Sorry, no. He wants to transform [12 8 8 6 4 3 3] into [12 9 6 5 ] with intermediate step [12 9 6 4 4] where duplicate elements with value n will be replaced by a single entry with value n+1.

Comment: @knivil: Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to the problem.

I have one `std::vector` `incremented` holding the values that are incremented if duplicates are found.

The `while` loop runs as long as there are duplicates to be removed, increments the found duplicate and adds it to the `incremented` vector.

The vector is being sorted after each run to ensure the values are being removed properly and so that the output shows correctly.

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <vector>     // std::vector
#include <functional> // std::greater
#include <algorithm>  // std::sort

bool remove_duplicates(std::vector<int>& vec, std::vector<int>& incremented)
{ // return true if there is work, false otherwise
   bool work_done { false };
   for (int i = 1; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
      if (vec[i] == vec[i - 1]) {
         incremented.push_back(vec[i] + 1);
         auto it = vec.begin() + i;
         vec.erase(it - 1, it + 1);
         work_done = true;
      }
   }

   return work_done;
}

auto main() -> int
{
   std::vector<int> v { 12, 8, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3 };
   std::vector<int> incremented;

   while (remove_duplicates(v, incremented)) {
      for (const auto& i : incremented)
         v.push_back(i);
      std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>());
      incremented.clear();
   }

   // print result
   for (const auto& i : v)
      std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Output: `12 9 6 5`

Hope this appears useful.